# Hide or Remove ng-grid rows based on ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to hide/remove certain rows if they have a specific ng-class or if some boolean function returns true or false

I tried using rowTemplate with ng-class or ng-show/ ng-hide but this results in empty rows instead of removing the rows all together.

Note that I can't use filterText because my boolean function compares different cells to come to decision whether each row will be hidden/removed or not.

I've searched quite a bit and couldn't find anything, would appreciate if anyone has a solution to the above.

The following thread experiences a similar issue: [How to get ng-grid to hide certain rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456670/how-to-get-ng-grid-to-hide-certain-rows)

Comment: I guess I'm going to resort to that in the end

Answer (score 0):

Could you use *ng-show* / *ng-hide* based on a boolean from your model?

These directives work by setting the element styles to display:block to show and
display:none to hide as appropriate. They provide equivalent but inverse
functionality for showing and hiding based on the expression you pass to them.

Comment: I have used that, but it doesn't work. It still displays the row but without any data within it.

Comment: Did you place them on the <tr>? EDIT: Sorry I see you are using ng-grid

Comment: The rowTemplate looks like this:  $scope.rowTemplate = 
    '<div style="height: 100%"><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
    '<div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }"> </div>' +
    '<div ng-cell></div>' +
      '</div></div>'   . Not sure I can see a tr in there

Comment: @kkudi Yes sorry just new to angular myself I just read the example in the o reilly book this morning to show hide based on model data. I'm not familiar yet with ng-grid to help out there.