# angularjs ng-grid: parent child relations between the rows (hide/show rows)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I'm trying to implement rendering the ng-grid with predefined hidden rows and on some particular event I want to show them. I'm trying to simulate kind of parent-children relation between rows, but all rows will be rendered and placed in usual manner.

By default the "child" rows will be rendered as "collapsed"

[image]

When the parent item is clicked the children rows will be shown as expanded

[image]

I'm trying to find some solutions with **gridOptions** **rowTemplate** settings, but I hope somebody has already faced with this kind of problem and maybe you have already solved it and it would be very helpful if you can share your ideas/solutions.

Or if it's a new issue, what will be the best way to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I added a few fields to the model for id, parentId, and expanded. On ng-click of the toggle row, it calls toggleExpansion to set the expanded state for the row. ng-show determines whether to show a row based on the expanded flag.

I made a Plunker to demonstrate:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fOMMXePQhWAF4DOnF3dW?p=preview

Here are some links to related questions. See the caveats about the row height css solution in the second link.

[How to get ng-grid to hide certain rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456670/how-to-get-ng-grid-to-hide-certain-rows)

[Angular ng-grid row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094723/angular-ng-grid-row-height)