# displaying hierarchy in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a requirement to show a set of hierarchical data in a single column in the ng-grid with '+' to expand/collapse parent row.

I've looked at its grouping function, but doesn't seem to do the job for me.

My data would be like follows:

```
{
     {name: 'Parent 1', children: {}},
     {name: 'Parent 2', children: {{name: 'Child 1'}, {name: 'Child 2'}, {name: 'Child 3'}}},
     {name: 'Parent 3', children: {}},
}
```

I want it to display in the grid as follows, in the same column:

```
Parent 1
Parent 2
   Child 1
   Child 2
   Child 3
Parent 3
```

What is the best way to achieve this with ng-Grid? Should I use an alternative json object for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

See this related question and a plunker I wrote that does this kind of thing:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fOMMXePQhWAF4DOnF3dW?p=preview

[angularjs ng-grid: parent child relations between the rows (hide/show rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572132/angularjs-ng-grid-parent-child-relations-between-the-rows-hide-show-rows/23695979#23695979)